# phpspreadsheet failed to work on online server! running php version 7.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

[image: Testing online phpspreadsheet]

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

class ReportExport extends CI_Controller
{
    public function download()
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

        $filename = 'robert';

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $filename .'.xlsx"'); 
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $writer->save('php://output'); // download file 
     }
}
```

I have tried to run that function in codeigniter and i get that response from the browser that File not Found (on the online server) yet when i run it offline(on localhost/) it returns the excel file that i have created.

Please any ideas i can use to fix the error!

I am using php version 7.3.14 on the online server.

Answer (score 0):

Save as file in a deticates Folder on Server

```
//Path to the file on Server, eg /var/www/website/folder/name.xlsx
$PATH = <PATH>;
$writer->save($PATH);
```

Comment: Still giving the same message!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I hope you already resolved this issue.

If not, I was getting a similar message, as the online server did not have the ea-php73-php-zip extension installed and it was silently throwing a "PhpSpreadSheet Class ZipArchive not found" error.